# Nginx using wrong server block (only when ssl is enabled)

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, prometheus, reverse-proxy

I want to achieve the following scenario with `nginx`:

- https://prom.infra.example.com => proxy_pass to Prometheus docker container
- https://docs.infra.example.com => proxy_pass to Prometheus Doccusaurus container

The server file looks like this:

```
events {}

http {

  server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /fullchain-RSA.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /privkey-RSA.pem;
    server_name docs.infra.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://athena-docs;
    }
  }
  server {
    listen 443 ssl default;
    ssl_certificate /fullchain-RSA.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /privkey-RSA.pem;
    server_name prom.infra.example.com;

    location / {
     proxy_pass http://prometheus:9090;
    }
 
  }
}
```

Now when I visit https://docs.infra.example.com (I set it to the IP using the hostfile) it gives me the documentation site with SSL and no errors.
But when I visit https://prom.infra.example.com (also set to IP with the hostfile) it gives me the documentation site again. And this is the exact problem I would like to solve.

If I use port 80 and no ssl on both sites it works perfectly, each subdomain goes to the correct one.

Comment: Is it a typo, that both your `server` blocks have the same `server_name`? Also, you haven't said anything about path prefix for prometheus, why is only it proxied?

Comment: Okay i tried it without the path prefix on prometheus, and the server block was fixed, somehow got jumbled up during copying to stack overflow

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, it is still the same problem as described in the question